# How can I still keep my old sessions after I override them?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a product and checkout page. In the product page when a button is pressed I do this

```
Session["code"] = productLabel.Text;
Session["description"] = descriptionTextBox.Text;
Session["price"] = priceLabel.Text;
Response.Redirect("cart.aspx");
```

Then in the cart page I have

```
if ((Session["code"] != null))
    {code = (Session["code"]).ToString();}

if ((Session["description"] != null))
    { description = (Session["description"]).ToString(); }

 if ((Session["price"] != null))
    {price = (Session["price"]).ToString(); }

  string item = code + " " + description + " " + price;
  cartList.Items.Add(item);
```

This works, however my problem is when I then add another product to the list, it overrides my first item so theirs only one item in there at a time. How can I keep track of whats currently/previously in there?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to rethink the entire concept and store some custom class instead, one thing you can do is create a list of items in the cart and store that list in the Session.

```
[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public string Code {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public string Price {get;set;}
}

List<Item> cart=new List<Item>();
Item item=new Item();
item.Code=productLabel.Text;
item.Description=descriptionTextBox.Text;
item.Price=priceLabel.Text;
cart.Add(item);
Session["cart"]=cart;

//then later pull it out...
List<Item> cart=Session["cart"] as List<Item>; //youll want to check for null etc
//and add another item
Item newItem=new Item();
newItem.Code=productLabel.Text;
newItem.Description=descriptionTextBox.Text;
newItem.Price=priceLabel.Text;
cart.add(newItem);
```

There's a ton wrong with your architecture. For instance, an enterprising individual could use their browser's tools to change the value in `priceLabel.Text` and potentially pay less (or nothing!) for their order. But hopefully this gives you an idea about how to proceed.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Item
{
    public string Code {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public string Price {get;set;}
}
```

you can create kind of like a in memory cache to store your items:

```
public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string,List<Item>> myMemoryCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,List<Item>>();
```

and use this as the data source.

You can use the same "key" for multiple entries or  you an change this to whatever you like.

Be sure to initialize this in your App_Start